# Why large volume of selling done at the beginning and end of day?

Tags: stock-markets

Why large volumes of selling done at the beginning and end of day? Is there data available which can say who made these selling?

[image]

Comment: Possibly because mutual funds &c do their buying & selling at the end of the day?  That is, if I want to withdraw some money from my account, and I log in and enter the trade right now (OK, this time tomorrow since markets are closed today), the trade in my account won't actually be executed until the the markets close, and the company will have to total all such trades and buy or sell to cover them at the start of business the next day.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of stock specific as well as market  and international news  reported after our markets close as well as before the open the next day.  At the open, traders react to that news.